# PHP add text to the Imagick object, the text appears garbled, spaces and question marks appear

Tags: php, text, character-encoding, imagick

I am trying to add some text on an Imagick object,
but I am getting spaces and question marks.

```
$canvas = new Imagick("4093aeb.jpeg");  
$canvas->setImageFormat('jpg');  
  
$text = new Imagick();  
$text->newImage(800, 800, 'none');  
$text->setImageFormat('jpg');  
  
$draw = new ImagickDraw();  
$draw->setFontWeight(900);
$draw->setTextKerning(3);
$draw->setFont('./boola.woff');
$draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#ebebeb'));  
$draw->setFontSize(80);  
$text->annotateImage($draw, 490, 300, 92, "Home");
$draw->setFillColor(new ImagickPixel('#ebebeb'));   
$text->annotateImage($draw, 230, 300, 85, 'Zengyu');
$shadow_layer = clone $text;  
$shadow_layer->setImageBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('#5f5f5f'));  
$shadow_layer->shadowImage(200, 2.5, 0, 0);  
$shadow_layer->compositeImage($text, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0 );  
$canvas->compositeImage($shadow_layer, imagick::COMPOSITE_DEFAULT, 0, 0); 
header("Content-type: image/jpg;");
echo $canvas->getImageBlob();
```

As a result I get
[image]

I want the text to be displayed normally, as shown below

[image]

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried another font? Try with a ttf.

Comment: Yes, tried other fonts, the text still appears with spaces and question marks. I use imagemagick syntax in linux, and the text can be displayed correctly. But using php Imagick on linux, there is a problem with the text. This problem occurs on linux, but it is completely fine on windows.

Comment: I tried that code on Ubuntu 22 with PHP 8.1.2 and works exactly as expected, but without a font. Maybe your PHP file has not a UTF8 encoding?